# Is there a way to paste the value from google sheet with same format and paste it in p tag?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am having a problem on how can i paste the value from google sheet to p tag. I tried to create textarea and put the value there, the result is perfect. However the result i want is to put the value in p element.

```
function showData(myObj){
  var updateDump = myObj.updateDump;
  var dump = JSON.parse(updateDump);
  var li="";
  for(var a = dump.length-1; a >= 1; a--){
    if(dump[a][4] != ""){
      var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
      var t = document.createTextNode(dump[a][4]);
      x.background =  "transparents" ;
      alert(x.value = dump[a][4]);
      x.value = dump[a][4];
      var test = x.value;
      
      li += "<li style='background-color: white;'>"+
                  "<div id='updates' style='background-color: #F5F5F5; border:1px solid #ddd; text-align: left; padding:5px; font-size:17px;'>"+
                    '<b><font color="red">*</font>'+dump[a][0]+'</b>'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<p style=""><span style="display:none;">'+dump[a][0]+'</span>'+test+'</p>'+
               '</li>';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML = li;
}
```

**Result of that code**

The marketing and promotional SMS templates listed below work because they are attention grabbers, they use powerful calls to action, they create a sense of urgency, and they share information in a clear and concise manner. Feel free to experiment with the wording of your messages, monitor their performance and tweak them based on your audience’s response. 1. Sales Joe’s Auto Repair is having a Buy 3 Get 1 Free tyre sale until the end of July. Visit Joe’s Auto Repair today on 21st Street for sizes and prices. 2. Loyalty Programme Receive discounts on tasty lunch specials. Text “LUNCH” to 777-343-555 and get a 2% discount on your next order! Your Daily Food. 3. Events Keep the kids happy this summer with free entry to the Paintball Centre throughout the whole of August. Call us back to book a date: 555-4545-777. 4. Opening Times No more running out of the office at 4pm on Fridays to find a new dress! Lucy’s Closet is now open until 8pm. Find your closest store: lucy.com/stores. 5. New Website All your favourite books at your reach! Gottingham Bookstore is now mobile. Best deals for 3 days only, hurry up: m.bookstore.com. 6. Invitation to Subscribe Be the first to know about discounts and offers at Bethany Beauty! Click here to subscribe: store.com/coupons-deals.

**Expected result**

The marketing and promotional SMS templates listed below work because they are attention grabbers, they use powerful calls to action, they create a sense of urgency, and they share information in a clear and concise manner. Feel free to experiment with the wording of your messages, monitor their performance and tweak them based on your audience’s response.

1. Sales
   Joe’s Auto Repair is having a Buy 3 Get 1 Free tyre sale until the end of July. Visit Joe’s Auto Repair today on 21st Street for sizes and prices.
2. Loyalty Programme
   Receive discounts on tasty lunch specials. Text “LUNCH” to 777-343-555 and get a 2% discount on your next order! Your Daily Food.
3. Events
   Keep the kids happy this summer with free entry to the Paintball Centre throughout the whole of August. Call us back to book a date: 555-4545-777.
4. Opening Times

Comment: Try using `<p><pre>somethinghere</pre></p>` tag as it preserve formatting

Comment: Not yet but ill try that one. Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `Is there a way to paste the value from google sheet with same format and paste it in p tag?`. Especially, I cannot understand about `paste the value from google sheet with same format`. Can I ask you about the sample input and output you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike what i am trying to ask is the value from google sheet which it has specific formatting will get the same format when i pull it out and put the value in P element

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to copy not only the cell value but also the cell format. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Solar <pre></pre> it works but the text over lapse the li element.

Comment: @Tanaike Exactly

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your goal. So when you provide the sample input and output you expect, I think that it will help to propose the modified script. How about this?

Comment: @Newbie, can you share a screenshot?